# Is it possible to dynamically load a script into a div that references local variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scope

Imagine the following two files:

**test.html**

```
<div id="stuff"></div>
<button onclick="doStuff()">Magic</button>
<script>
var foo = new function() {
    this.bar = function() {
        return "THE MAGIC!";
    };
};

function doStuff() {
    $('#stuff').load('stuffToDo.html');
}
</script>
```

**stuffToDo.html**

```
<div><script>document.write(foo.bar());</script></div>
```

I would like to insert the dynamic content from stuffToDo.html into the div in test.html. I've found that using jQuery.load() or jQuery.get() with subsequent $('#stuff').html(data) seems to cause the script to get executed before insertion and thus before it is in the scope of the foo singleton. Is there a better way to do this or at least a way to put the content into the div without executing or removing the script tags then running an eval on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend actually inserting a script tag, then adding to innerHTML.

In plain Javascript:

```
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.src = stuff.js
document.body.appendChild(script);

//in script.js

var stuff=document.getElementsById('stuff');
stuff.innerHTML=foo.bar()
```

Comment: On the right track, that does appear to execute in scope. However, I would still like to load a html file instead of a js file because the final implementation will have more complex formatting. I guess I could separate it into two files, a sort of template loaded with ajax then a script called on that template afterwards loaded with this method.

Comment: That is definitely the more modern take on including scripts. `document.write()`ing from an included html file can result in a world of trouble.. ie wiped pages if you do this after pageload.

Comment: So a new requirement has arisen in that scripts must be able to 'refresh' or be run a second time. I've decided to split the stuffToDo.html into a layout.html with a bunch of named divs and a script.js. Everything works the first time if I ajax the layout into the div then call the script afterward. If I want to run the script again are there any problems with or alternatives to just appending it again? Other than a few dozen duplicate script tags in the DOM anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Using document.write after the document is loaded will rewrite the whole document, so if this works the entire page will be blank with the text 'THE MAGIC!', so if you don't want that to happen you will want to use jQuery to insert the data instead of document.write.

```
<div><script>$('body').append(foo.bar());</script></div>
```

Inserting a script like that can have different results on different browsers, it's better to use a script include instead. Your function foo is in the global scope, so you can use it in your included script. Use [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
function doStuff() {
    $.getScript('/path/to/script.js');
}
```

Then the script can do this:

```
$('#stuff').html(foo.bar());
```

Comment: Good catch with document.write, I'll use jQuery instead. I would prefer not to use getScript since the html file contains formatting information. I guess I can go with the previously mentioned separation of that template and script.